# Скрыть блок с помощью анимации css

Tags: css, css-animation

Всем привет. Подскажите как сделать, чтобы после анимации блок не появлялся
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zb6dc10f/)

```js
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('.test').addClass('animate');
}, 2000);
```

```css
.test {
width : 100px;
height: 100px;
background: green;
}
.animate {  
  animation: zoomOut; 
  animation-duration: 2s; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

добавьте `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` к вашему классу `.animate`

> `CSS` свойство `animation-fill-mode` определяет, как нужно применять стили
> к объекту анимации до и после ее выполнения.
>
> `forwards` - По окончании анимации элемент сохранит стили последнего
> ключевого кадра, который определяется значениями [animation-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction) и
> [animation-iteration-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count)

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.test').addClass('animate');
}, 2000);
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.animate {
  animation: zoomOut;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test"></div>
```

Более подробно об `animation-fill-mode` можете прочитать по ссылке - [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

можно через небольшой изврат:

```
.finish {
  display: none;
}

setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('.test').addClass('animate');
}, 3000);

setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('.test').addClass('finish');
}, 4900);
```

если требуется, чтобы объект исчез полностью и не занимал места, в противном случае объект не будет виден, но место под него будет оставлено